# Expanding a function into a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I am trying to follow a proof in QFT notes, however I am unable to follow this step - it's basically Laurent/Taylor expansion but I have very little experience with it.

It's claimed that:

$$\frac{\pi}{2d}\frac{e^{a\pi/d}}{(e^{a\pi/d}-1)^2}=\frac{d}{2\pi a^2} - \frac{\pi}{24d} + O(a^2)$$

When $a<<d$.

Could someone show me the trick how it's obtained?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361826/lim-n-to-infty-e-sqrt-n-left1-frac1-sqrt-n-rightn/1361828#1361828

Comment: If I express both exponentials as power series I end up with a ratio of power series, I'm not sure how to proceed. What if I knew that first term is proportional to $a^{-2}$, is using Cauchy's integral theorem can somehow solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a<<d\iff \dfrac ad<<1, \dfrac{a\pi}d<<1, $ let  $\dfrac{a\pi}d=2x$

$$F=\dfrac{e^{2x}}{(e^{2x}-1)^2}=\dfrac1{(e^x-e^{-x})^2}$$

Use $e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$

$$F=\dfrac1{4\left[x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\right]}=\dfrac1{4x^2\left[1+\dfrac{x^2}6+O(x^4)\right]}$$

As $1+\dfrac{x^2}6+O(x^4)\approx1+\dfrac{x^2}6,$

Use [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series),
$$F=\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{x^2}6\right)^{-1}}{4x^2}=\dfrac{1-\dfrac{x^2}6+\left(\dfrac{x^2}6\right)^2+O(x^6)}{4x^2}=\dfrac1{4x^2}-\dfrac1{24}+O(x^2)$$

Now replace $2x$ with  $\dfrac{a\pi}d$ and observe that $O(x^2)$ corresponds to $O(a^2)$

Comment: I solved it couple of minutes ago, but your method is more elegant, thank you for your work it was very helpful!